# Why does (` `) gives a list and $() gives only one argument

Tags: bash

I might not word this properly, pls edit.
Say I have:

```
lst=(`ls $1`)
echo $lst #this gives the first element of the list
```

but then when I tried this:

```
lst=$(ls $1)
echo $lst #this gives me all the files under argument directory
```

Comment: The first command gives me an error, what shell are you using?

Comment: I used the bash shell, sorry forgot to add `$`

Comment: You might benefit from "Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?",  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: See Dickey's answer.

Comment: The feature is standard, and the question gave no pretext for soapboxing about the merits of the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash.

The first example `lst=(`ls $1`)` creates an array of values in the var lst.
As this code will show:

```
lst=(`ls .`); printf '%s\n' "${lst[@]}"
```

The second example `lst=$(ls $1)` executes `ls $1` but only the output (concatenated as one long string) is assigned to the var `lst`.

Maybe what you meant to compare was:

```
lst=( `ls $1`)
lst=($(ls $1))
```

And indeed `` `...` `` is exactly equivalent to `$(...)`.

And both commands will create an array of values in `lst`

Answer (score 2):

First, why `$1` (first argument) here?
Second, `echo lst` will just write `lst`, not the contents of the variable. Presumably you want `echo $lst`.

As you are using `bash(1)`, the assignment with parenthesis creates an array, and without index that evaluates to it's first element:

```
lst=(1 2 3)
echo $lst       # prints 1
echo ${lst[0]}  # prints 1
echo ${lst[1]}  # prints 2
echo ${lst[*]}  # prints 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The first example

```
lst=(`ls $1`)
```

would be the same as

```
lst=( $(ls $1 ) )
```

and both appear to work with bash.